# Keep getting (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this) Error In Simple Haskell Function

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm just playing around with Haskell monads and I keep getting an error that I can't seem to fix. My code segment uses the state Monad to add the first two characters from a string together and return them as part of the state. My "put" line keeps giving me the error:

```
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadState [a] m
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* When checking the inferred type
    testH :: forall (m :: * -> *) a. MonadState [a] m => [a] -> m [a]
```

How can I fix this? Extending the language is not an option, I just need to know how I can change my code to get it to work

```
test xs = 
 runState (testH (tail xs)) ((head xs):[])

testH xs =
 do
  a <- get 
  put ((head xs):a)
  b <- get
  return b
```

Comment: Are you importing `Control.Monad.State`? If so, try importing `Control.Monad.Trans.State` instead.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I know what you mean by "Extending the language is not an option". If you are just playing around with monads, why not add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` to the top of your code?

Comment: "Extending the language is not an option", except that you are using `MultiParamTypeClasses` just by having `MonadState` in scope and therefore have already extended the language.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by either enabling `FlexibleContexts` as it suggests, or by changing your function to work on something more general than lists.

The issue is that Haskell does not allow non-type variable things in a context. If you write out the types of your functions (which you should be doing anyway), you get

```
testH :: (Monad m,MonadState [a] m) => [a] -> m [a]
```

which means it is a function that takes a list of values and returns an action in some monad that has the ability to keep a state of a list of values of the same type as the input. Unfortunately, the `[a]` bit in the context is invalid Haskell because it has a non-type variable thing (namely the list type constructor).

**The best solution here is to just enable the extension, which *allows* non-type variable things in contexts.** It's not dangerous, it just relaxes the standard. In fact, multi-parameter typeclasses (such as `MonadState`) are not valid Haskell, so you are already using language extensions whether you like it or not.

If this is really not an option, you could change it to `(Monad m,SomeTypeclass f,MonadState (f a) m)`, and rewrite your functions to work with any constructor that follows the `SomeTypeclass` of your choice. This removes the list type constructor from the type and allows the code to work without `FlexibleContexts`.